# What are the related papers for Kaldi's TDNN and LSTM?

Tags: kaldi

What are the most related papers for the following script in Kaldi.

```
egs/wsj/s5/local/nnet3/run_tdnn_lstm.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A TIME-RESTRICTED SELF-ATTENTION LAYER FOR ASR](http://www.danielpovey.com/files/2018_icassp_attention.pdf)

Daniel Povey, Hossein Hadian, Pegah Ghahremani, Ke Li, Sanjeev Khudanpur